# What is the best way to bypass China firewall to allow SSH deploy@**.com

Tags: ssh, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I am trying to bypass the china firewall and allow `SSH deploy@**.com` at the command console.  This is because I need to test the games I wrote on apps.facebook.com/**.  I tried VPN (both pptp and openvpn), but they aren't that great as connection speed slows down significantly.  Since I am deploying the game in another site, my browser needs to download the game, which is super slow.

What are ways of bypassing the firewall other than getting a VPN?  I was thinking maybe have a computer outside China and using *teamviewer* to access...

Answer (score 1):

VPN should not slow down or shape your speed anyway, unless the VPN administrator intentionally does that.

If possible, get a Amazon EC2 micro - free tier as your bridge and do what you want from that virtual machine (Xen based), could be in APAC, US or Europe which is outside the GFW.

I don't fully understand what you mean by SSH deploy@**.com, are you trying to ssh to a remote host to run scripts on that host? If you can explain what you are trying better, folks here can better help you.